# Creating a javascript regex function for a filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, web

I need to create a regex function that will filter a list of article feeds that contain the selected strings.

This code below adds to the variable 'tf' the selected strings when the user clicks on a filter option. The variable 'tf' might look like this: "Vanilla ice cream, video games," with "vanilla ice cream" and "video games" being the keywords.

```
$(".trending").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("selected");

    var temp22 = "";
    $(".trending.selected").each(function(i, e) {
        temp22 += $(this).attr("id").substr(9) + ", ";
    });

    tf = temp22;
    filter_trend();
});
```

The piece of code below filters the article feed by searching the list of articles to see if it contains the keywords. 
$(f2) is the list of articles and I filter it by returning only ones that contain the keywords in its html.

```
function filter_trend(){
    var tfilter = new RegExp (tf, "i");

    if (tf == ""){
        filter_load();
        return;
    }

    if (f == "")
        var f2 = ".article";
    else
        var f2 = f;

    $(f2).hide();
    //alert(f2);
    $(f2).filter(function(i,e) {
        return i < list_length && tfilter.test($(e).html());
    }).show();

}
```

Is there a way to use regex or should I approach this with another method?

Comment: Why use regex when you can use `.indexOf`? http://jsfiddle.net/d2M5n/

Comment: As an aside, it's not really good practice to rely on global variables to pass information around, when you could pass `tf` to `filter_trend()` as a function parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I was unaware of the 'or' operator in regex.

adding '|' in between every keyword solves the problem.